# Changing page content with custom scheme in WebKitGTK1

Tags: webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

I have an app using the WebKitGTK1 API with WebKit-GTK 2.4.9 on Linux.  (This is the current version in Debian Jessie and versions 2.5+ don't support the v1 API.)

I've implemented a custom URI scheme for loading entire basic page content by using a [`resource-request-starting`](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebFrame.html#WebKitWebFrame-resource-request-starting) handler, which parses the incoming URI via `webkit_web_resource_get_uri` and if it matches the custom scheme, generates some HTML content and calls [`webkit_network_request_set_uri`](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitNetworkRequest.html#webkit-network-request-set-uri) to replace the original URI with a base64'd `data:` URI containing the content to render.  (This is similar to the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238483/how-to-handle-a-custom-url-scheme-in-webkit-gtk).)

This mostly works well, and my handler is called on each request (including repeated requests with the same original URI) and generates the correct content -- but somewhere upstream the browser appears to render only the first returned data for any given original URI, even if the data URI I generate is different.

Possibly of note is that [`webkit_web_resource_get_uri`](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebResource.html#webkit-web-resource-get-uri) returns the original non-`data:` URI even after calling `webkit_network_request_set_uri`, so I assume this URI is being cached, and in turn is then being used as a key in some higher-level component to cache the data instead of using the *real* URI from the request.

Unfortunately this appears to be a `G_PARAM_CONSTRUCT_ONLY` property and there doesn't appear to be any public API to set and/or clear it so that it uses the rewritten URI of the request instead.  Is there some way to force GTK to set the property after construction anyway?  As far as I can tell it does have a setter method internally, and the getter would do the Right Thing™ if the internal property were reset to NULL.

Or is there some better method to force WebKit to render the new `data:` URI despite anything it thinks to the contrary?

---

For the moment I've worked around it by including the values that make it generate different data in the original custom URI (passed to `webkit_web_view_load_uri` or in links in the generated page).  This **does** work but it's a bit ugly, and could be problematic if I forget to add something in the future, or if something changes generation but is not known in advance.  It seems a bit silly that it goes to all the trouble of raising the event that generates the correct data, only to throw it away later, (presumably) due to an URI comparison on the wrong URI.

I suppose using a known-unique value (eg. sequential incrementing id) would also work, and resolve some of the unknown-in-advance issues, but that's no less ugly.

Comment: FYI that version of WebkitGtk is unsupported and insecure. Move onto Webkit2.

Comment: @TingPing does the V2 API support what the OP wants to do? I know they're different in terms of capabilities but I forget *how* different.

Comment: The V2 API does have a more integrated way of doing custom schemes, which _might_ help with this issue (since it's at least a different code path).  However I don't consider this a valid answer, as the V2 API also forces multiprocess, which I don't want.

Comment: Fedora is removing all apps that have not transitioned to V2. You'd better hope Debian doesn't follow.

Comment: You're probably hitting the page cache. You might want to investigate ways to disable it for your page:

https://webkit.org/blog/427/webkit-page-cache-i-the-basics/