# How to register a custom URL scheme handler with WebKit for Windows?

Tags: windows, webkit

I have a Windows application showing web content using WebKit.
Now I'd like some specific URLs to be handled locally by the application instead of loaded from the server.
Let's say the javascript code of the page tries to request `http://example.com/SomeFcgiRequest.fcgi`.
This request shall be catched and the data of the response shall be generated by the application.

My idea was to use the *WebResourceLoadDelegate* for changing the URL scheme to a custom scheme (e.g. `custom://example.com/SomeFcgiRequest.fcgi`) and register a scheme handler for handling these requests.

There is a way to do it for MacOS/iOS using the *WKURLSchemeHandler* protocol and registering it with *setURLSchemeHandler:forURLScheme:*.
For the GTK port I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238483/how-to-handle-a-custom-url-scheme-in-webkit-gtk).
But I couldn't figure out how this can be done using the Windows port of WebKit. For me it seems to be not (yet) implemented.

Can someone point me in the right direction?